# Paper js - Raster onClick event attached only to position Point

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am using PaperJS and I need to use an existing set of icons that I can receive as a base64 string (that's a given I can't change). I have no problem rendering the rasters.
However when I set them a position like so:

```
    const myRaster = new Raster(<someBase64>);
    myRaster.position = new Point(receivedX, recievdY);
    myRaster.onClick = () => console.log('raster click');
```

The onClick event would only work if I click exactly on [x,y] point assigned to the `position` property.
The X and Y are received form a data base and are in accordance to other visible elements.

I played around in the PaeprJS website, and without using a `new Point` position the onClick works all around the image.

My solution for now is creating an invisible polygon (new Path.RegularPolygon) and to attach to onClick event to it and it works.
However, there's must be a simpler solution and would love to understand what I am missing here.

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue with real data (http://shorturl.at/hkwV0). Could you give us a link to a live example reproducing the error so that we can help you better ?

Comment: @sasensi seems to be related to a problem with the encoding of or the actual svg I am using. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the SVG was partially created programmaticly and had a lot of whitespace around it.
Testing with base64 encoded SVGs from various different sources worked as expected